# Omitting the "I" from "I am" the second clause in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

For example I've written:

> "I have an interest in rock climbing and am a member of the
>   mountaineers Society."

My friend thinks it has to be:

> "I have an interest in rock climbing and ***I*** am a member of the
>   mountaineers Society."

which I think sounds bad.

Which is right?

Comment: Both are equally right.

Comment: And the first (without the additional "I") feels more natural and fluid.  The latter (using the additional "I") feels stiltled and a little clunky.

Comment: As @RegDwigнt says, both are right, but in the second example (only), you need a comma before *and*. You also need to use upper case for *Mountaineers* (if it is a title) or lower case for *society* (if it is merely a description).

Comment: I don't think the comma is actually necessary (or perhaps even desirable) but it's certainly possible to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this since you are still talking about yourself and the sentence still refers to your interest/connection with climbing. Also, just a small observation mountaineers Society should be: Mountaineers Society (possibly with an apostrophe).